# Поиск прямоугольника на изображении

Tags: python, opencv

**Задача**: 
Найти жёсткий диск на фото, определить его угол и контуры

**Проблема:**
Не всегда удаётся найти правильный контур диска.

В коде я делаю изображения серыми, блюрю, нахожу разницу между ними и определяю контуры, но решение не точное. Хотелось бы вашей помощи.

```
firstFrame = cv2.imread(bg_im)  # Фоновое изображение без диска
frame_img = cv2.imread(frame)   # Изображение с диском

gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)
firstFrame = cv2.cvtColor(firstFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
firstFrame = cv2.GaussianBlur(firstFrame, (21, 21), 0)

frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(firstFrame, gray)
thresh = cv2.threshold(frameDelta, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

c = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[0]

rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect)

x1 = box[0][0]
x2 = box[1][0]
x4 = box[3][0]

y1 = box[0][1]
y2 = box[1][1]
y4 = box[3][1]

perimeter_1_4 = sqrt((x4 - x1)**2 + (y1 - y4)**2)
perimeter_1_2 = sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)

box = np.int0(box)
corner = list(rect)[2]

if perimeter_1_4 > perimeter_1_2:
    corner = -(90 - corner)    

cv2.drawContours(frame_img,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
```

[image: Фон. Без диска]
[image: Фон. Без диска]

Comment: На картинках случайно не конвейер? Просто если диск движется, то, возможно, выделение контуров окажется проще при работе с межкадровой разницей.

Comment: #alexis031182, да, здесь конвеер. Думал на такой возможностью, но это только в последнюю очередь. Тяжеловато будет внедрить это в структуру самого приложения.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как только речь заходит о применении размытия с большим размером ядра, то, к сожалению, получается необратимая деформация объекта интереса. Объект контурами вроде и выделен, но при этом по своим размерам, форме (а подчас и положению) может иметь значительное расхождение с оригиналом. Стоит ли говорить, что морфологические операции (эрозия, дилатация), наложенные поверх, лишь усугубляют проблему.

В ситуации с представленными изображениями сложность возникает ещё и от того, что лента конвейера имеет весьма различимые следы производственного пользования. Это царапины, пятна и прочие элементы подобного рода, которые на фоновом изображении и изображении с объектом интереса имеют разное положение, да и вообще в деталях различаются значительно. Этот момент становится принципиальным, когда производится попиксельное вычитание одного изображения из другого.

В целом задача сводится к тому, чтобы не повредив сам объект, попытаться выделить его на общем фоне. Попробуем пойти от обратного и вместо того, чтобы применять размытие повысим резкость краёв.

```
void subtractPyr(const cv::Mat &src_mat, cv::Mat &dst_mat, int iterations) {
    std::vector<cv::Size> sizes(iterations);

    cv::Mat mat = src_mat.clone();
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
        sizes[iterations-(i+1)] = mat.size();
        cv::pyrDown(mat, mat);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
        cv::pyrUp(mat, mat, sizes.at(i));

    cv::subtract(mat, src_mat, dst_mat);
}

cv::Mat src1_mat = cv::imread("foreground.jpg");
cv::Mat src2_mat = cv::imread("background.jpg");

cv::Mat gry1_mat, gry2_mat;
cv::cvtColor(src1_mat, gry1_mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::cvtColor(src2_mat, gry2_mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

subtractPyr(gry1_mat, gry1_mat, 5);
subtractPyr(gry2_mat, gry2_mat, 5);
```

Изображение с объектом интереса:

[image: Изображение с объектом интереса]

Фоновое изображение:

[image: Фоновое изображение]

Несмотря на то, что фоновое изображение имеет свой набор шумов, тем не менее оно содержит и те детали, которые полезно вычесть из изображения с объектом интереса. После этого можно выполнить бинаризацию.

```
cv::Mat gry_mat = gry1_mat - gry2_mat;

cv::Mat bin_mat;
cv::threshold(gry_mat, bin_mat, 1, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY | cv::THRESH_OTSU);
```

Получим следующую маску:

[image: Маска с объектом интереса]

Здесь хорошо заметна одна из проблем, связанная с неверно подобранным освещением. Левый верхний угол объекта интереса частично растворён, что не позволяет произвести поиск контура, опоясывающего объект, с корректным результатом.

Так или иначе продолжим именно через поиск контуров и отсеивание их по площади с эмпирически подобранным размером. Их иерархия больше не потребуется, а значит объединим все точки в один единственный большой контур.

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(bin_mat.clone(), contours
    , cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

std::vector<cv::Point> big_contour;

for(auto itr = contours.begin(); itr != contours.end(); ++itr) {
    if(cv::contourArea(*itr) > 300.) {
        const std::vector<cv::Point> &contour = *itr;
        for(auto itr2 = contour.begin(); itr2 != contour.end(); ++itr2) {
            big_contour.push_back(*itr2);
        }
    }
}
```

Если нарисовать большой контур, то можно увидеть, что лишние детали на изображении более не захватываются, а сам он в целом лежит внутри границ объекта интереса.

[image: Изображение с большим контуром]

Остаётся получить опоясывающий объект интереса прямоугольник.

```
cv::RotatedRect rc = cv::minAreaRect(big_contour);

cv::Point2f points[4];
rc.points(points);

// Нарисуем его.
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    cv::line(dst_mat, points[i], points[(i+1)%4], cv::Scalar(0,0,255));
```

Как хорошо видно на следующем изображении полученный прямоугольник совершенно не идеально описывает объект интереса. Эта проблема связана с оптической деформацией этого самого объекта, а также с наличием довольно широкой тени, присутствующей с левой его стороны. К сожалению, эти проблемы нельзя устранить иначе, кроме как подстройкой объектива камеры и освещения.

[image: Изображение с опоясывающим объект интереса прямоугольником]